# how to add text using java script in below code:

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to add "On Plant & Machinery" in below code using javascript in selenium.

after adding above text it is look like :
On Plant & Machinery

Please help.

Comment: please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your code trials and error (if any)?

Comment: Please add code snippets or error encountered for further help.

Answer (score 0):

To set the text **On Plant & Machinery** as the `innerHTML` within the *WebElement* you can use the following solution:

- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

  ```
  document.querySelector(".table_column").textContent="On Plant & Machinery";
  ```
- [python](/questions/tagged/python):

  ```
  driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('table_column')[0].value='On Plant & Machinery'")
  ```
- [java](/questions/tagged/java):

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('table_column')[0].setAttribute('value','On Plant & Machinery')")
  ```